# Count of new users by Year SQL Query

Tags: sql, count

We have a subscription based business and a table with the account holders details and the signup date

I want to do a query that gets the count of new signups for each year.

I.E.

Table

```
USER / SIGNUPDATE

User 1 06/08/2013

User 2 06/08/2013

User 3 06/08/2014

User 4 06/08/2014

User 5 06/08/2014

User 6 06/08/2014

User 7 06/08/2014

User 8 06/08/2015
```

Returning record set

```
CountOfNewUsers2013 / CountOfNewUsers2014 / CountOfNewUsers2015

2 / 5 / 1
```

I can get the count for each year individually but not sure how or if I can group them together in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are trying to display the results in one row horizontally. This is not the way this data is typically displayed. it can be done that way, it's just a lot more work. I am assuming you are using SQL Server because you haven't mentioned which system. Here is how to do it with multiple rows (in two columns):

```
SELECT year(SIGNUPDATE) as [Year]
, count(USER)  as CountOfNewUsers
FROM IDontKnowYourTableNameSorry
GROUP BY year(SIGNUPDATE)
```

Group by and count are the key features here if you want to look up their documentation.

Comment: It's just a count of signups by year, but not new ones.

Comment: I think the OP and I had the same understanding of "new" since signups are always new, by definition. They did accept my answer. This is from 5 years ago. Do you have a similar question?

Answer (score 2):

```
select year(signupdate), count(*) as newusers
from tablename
group by year(signupdate)
```

You have to `group by` year of signupdate column.

Comment: YEAR is a product specific function, please tell us which dbms! (No one specified in question.) ANSI SQL has EXTRACT(YEAR FROM col).

Comment: excellent that did the job

SELECT year(dtm_signupdate) as SignUpYear, count(*) as newusers
FROM tbl_Account
GROUP BY year(dtm_signupdate)
ORDER BY SignUpYear